# How can I paint on a specific pixel in BlackBerry 10, Qt QML Cpp

Tags: qt, qml, blackberry-10

I simply want to paint a 1 pixel dot on a specific point on the screen. Is there anyway to do that? In QML or cpp?

Answer (score 0):

Rectangle QML item should works good for you: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-rectangle.html

If you need to draw something more specific and more flexible, then you can customize QDeclarativeItem in C++, unset QGraphicsItem::ItemHasNoContents flag in your custom class and implement paint method. More details: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdeclarativeitem.html